# Можно ли принципы отстаивать как убеждения?

Tags: тавтология

> Он имел очень ясные принципы и каждым днём своей жизни отстаивал их
>   как глубочайшие убеждения.

Как лучше поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Он имел очень ясные принципы и каждым днём своей жизни отстаивал их.**

И всё.

"Каждым днём жизни отстаивал" – это другой вопрос. Тоже не очень звучит.

Answer (score 4):

Кем-то изложенные (*чужие*, готовые) принципы *можно* отстаивать "как свои глубочайшие убеждения" (= сделав их своими), если же в начале предложения сказано, что они уже есть (они *свои*), остаётся только отстаивать их как таковые - не заменяя синонимом (в форме которого их зачем-то хотят отстаивать - можно и сразу было заявить об "отстаивании" без отдельного "наличия": отстаивать можно только *имеющиеся* убеждения/принципы).

Comment: Саш, ну скажи: как есть можно ль оставить?

Comment: Что-нибудь одно надо оставить, напр. _Он имел твёрдые убеждения (или ясные принципы), которые повседневно отстаивал всю свою жизнь._

Answer (score 1):

Он имел очень ясные принципы и каждым днём своей жизни отстаивал эти глубочайшие убеждения.